# Calling a command in Cron not working, but works if run by hand

Tags: cron

I have a bash script (clean.sh) that runs fine by hand but doesn't run when run from cron.

```
cd /usr/share/clean_addr/bin/
cleanme cleanme.ini
```

When the clean.sh script is by cron the cleanme exe is not found. I gave an absolute path to the cleanme exe but then its supporting library files were not found.

```
cd /usr/share/clean_addr/bin/
/usr/share/clean_addr/bin/cleanme cleanme.ini
```

The cron runs under the same user account as that in which the script ran manually. What do I need to set to get this to work.

Sincerely,
Stephen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that the cleanme application required environment variables that were set on the user account, but were not known by cron because cron doesn't resolve those settings. Explicitly setting the environment variables for cleanme in the .sh resolved the issue

```
CLEANME_PATH=/usr/share/clean_addr/bin/
export CLEANME_PATH
```

Comment: That was the root cause. The environment variables were not being recognized in the cron job. Had to explicitly set them.